# Add Selected Listbox Items to Textbox without resetting Textbox in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Currently, I am trying to allow a user to click an item in a list box (listBusFun) and add to a textbox (TextBox2).

I need the textbox NOT to reset as new selections are entered.

They may select only one item from the listbox, or they may select multiple at a time - but they all need to be added to a textbox.

If it is easier, I can code this behind a button as well.

I'm not really sure how to do this, but if you could help me out by commenting out the code so I can understand, I would appreciate it.

Attempted to write this:

```
Private Sub btnAddBusinessFunction_Click()  
TextBox2.Text = listBusFun.Text  
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you at least **TRY** something, first. This is not a forum where you solicit others to do your work for free, it's a place where ppl help others with *specific* problems implementing code. The whole "Please tell me what to do and how it works because I can't be bothered to use a search engine..." is tiresome.

Comment: Okay. Clearly I'm new and you don't have to be that rude about it. Thanks for the suggestion. What I have is: 

Private Sub btnAddBusinessFunction_Click()
TextBox2.Text = listBusFun.Text
End Sub

The problem is it only adds one at a time to the textbox and clears the others out.

Also, the whole "not using a search engine" thing is ridiculous. I haven't found any VBA specific answers and the C# & .Net aren't helpful. Moreover, I asked for it to be commented out because the code I have found for other languages is without comments, so I can't understand it to try to adapt it. Comments = HELPFUL

Comment: Code doesn't render in the comments, please revise your original question. Also, since you're new please review [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You're over writing it each time. You would have to loop through the multiples and concatenate it with a new line. I understand you're new here and looking for help, so I'm trying to cut you some slack, but please read this FAQ on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I understand that you're new here, but you have not given really any indication that you've read or understand how this forum works...

Comment: Thanks @ckuhn203 for that link. Very helpful and important perspective / points to consider. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest to attach this to a button. You need to iterate the items in the listbox, check to see if each one is selected, and if it is selected, then you append/concatenate it to another string.

> I haven't found any VBA specific answers

Because you're not asking the right question. This is not a problem about listboxes and textboxes or anything, it is simple string concatenation, only slightly complicated by the need to iterate over a list of items and append to the string if the item(s) selected.

Do you understand your own code? Every time you press the button, it's simply overwriting the value in your textbox:

```
Private Sub btnAddBusinessFunction_Click()  
    TextBox2.Text = listBusFun.Text  
End Sub
```

Now that I describe the process, does that make a little more sense?

```
Private Sub btnAddBusinessFunction_Click()
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Long

    'iterate the listbox items and concatente a string
    ' which we will append to the textbox's existing text
    For i = 0 To ListBusFun.ListCount - 1

        If ListBusFun.Selected(i) Then
            If str <> vbNullString Then str = str & ", "
            str = str & ListBusFun.List(i)
        End If

    Next

    'Append this to the existing text in the textbox
    TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & str

End Sub
```

Comment: The code I have is, take the selected list item and replace the text box with the selected item. I was sure I wasn't googling the right thing when I didn't yield any helpful results after an hour. I understand how it's not the passing of the values, its what is going on with the values. I also didn't realize I had to declare as string to add each new item because I didn't have to declare the incorrect code as a string. Thanks.

Comment: I get it. The difficulty when you're learning is that you don't even know what questions to ask. That is well-evidenced by your own admissions -- at a fundamental level you don't even know what you're doing. I'm not trying to be rude, but you are going to need to start with the very basics, a book, tutorial, or class would be beneficial to help you learn the basic concepts which are building blocks of programming in this or any other language (*every* language deals with strings, in one manner or another)